# How to write more than one link and how to count them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While coding an image downloader I was testing some functions and I want to store all the links in links.txt but it only write one link and in the run window it shows all the links that has been founded please help me to fix this problem, and also if the problem fixed I want to know how many links are there, I tried some function but it doesn't seem to work like I wanted to and thank you so much!

Here's the code so far:

```
# import random
# import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
        # name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
        # fullName = str(name) + ".jpg"
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('img'):
            image_links = link.get('src')
            if '.jpg' in image_links:
                raw_text = r'links.txt'
                fw = open(raw_text, 'w')
                for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                    fw.write(i+'\n')
                    fw.close()
                    fr = open('links.txt', 'r')
                    text = fr.read()
                    print(text)


Download_Image_from_Web("https://pixabay.com/")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the program based on original sample using `with` context for reference.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
        # name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
        # fullName = str(name) + ".jpg"
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        raw_text = 'links.txt'

        with open(raw_text, 'w') as fw:
            for link in soup.findAll('img'):
                image_links = link.get('src')
                if '.jpg' in image_links:
                    for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                        fw.write(i+'\n')

        with open(raw_text, 'r') as fr:
            text = fr.read()
            # print(text)
            print("Total {} images found:\n{}".format(len(text.splitlines()), text))

Download_Image_from_Web("https://pixabay.com/")
```

**EDIT1**: Remove the description on previous `with` sample in first paragraph.

**EDIT2**: Add image counts in output.

Comment: I added this code: `num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('links.txt'))
        print(num_lines)` and it works good thnx

Comment: Added the count in last print() with `str.splitlines()` for reference.

Comment: With context is unnecessary for file read if you are reading whole file at once you can directly use `file.read()`

Comment: You can use with context for reading large file line by line. Unless that it is an overkill to use with context for reading file data in a single go like this.

Comment: Context offers __enter__ and __exit__, not the iterable. File object itself **is** an iterator.
For this one-time script with particular interpreter, and not to update it in future,  it might be fine to leave w/o close(). However, as general practice, it is important to close resource explicitly. It is recommended to keep the rule to prevent from issues as fd limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file to write in `append` mode note in `write` mode. 
Basically `write` mode overwrites the file so your code will be

```
 fw = open(raw_text, 'a') #this opens file in append mode
 for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
     fw.write(i+'\n')
     fw.close()
     fr = open('links.txt', 'r')
     text = fr.read() #this prints all the written content for each line
     print(text)
```

You can print the entire written content at the end like this

```
     fw = open(raw_text, 'a') #this opens file in append mode
     for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
         fw.write(i+'\n')
         fw.close()
     fr = open('links.txt', 'r')
     text = fr.read() #this prints all the written content at the end.
     print(text)
```

If you need count of images then you can use `len` method on `image_links.split("\\n")` so in that case your code will be

```
      fw = open(raw_text, 'a') #this opens file in append mode
      Images= image_links.split("\\n")
      print "no of images = ",len(Images)
      for i in Images:
         fw.write(i+'\n')
         fw.close()
     fr = open('links.txt', 'r')
     text = fr.read() #this prints all the written content at the end
     print(text)
```

Comment: The solution is on direction. However, if we move the last read() into with context, it won't get full contents, in this particular case, no contents because there is no forced flush before close() implicitly handled.
        with open(raw_text, 'w') as fw:
            for link in soup.findAll('img'):
                image_links = link.get('src')
                if '.jpg' in image_links:
                    for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                        fw.write(i+'\n')

        with open(raw_text, 'r') as fr:
            text = fr.read()
            print(text)

Comment: Yeah i agree that hence removed `with` part from my answer now you can read the full context of written file if you go with this answer.

Comment: thank you so much it works however in the run window it each time it keep adding one link like: 1 12 123 1234 .....